# Specifying test dependencies in pyproject.toml and getting them installed with pip install -e

Tags: python, setuptools, python-packaging, pyproject.toml

I have a Python project with a `pyproject.toml` similar to the one below. I use `python build` to generate an package I use to install in production environments. For development environments, I use `pip install -e .`

I'm trying to figure out how to make sure test dependencies are installed for development environments, but not as part of a production environment.

```
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools>=61.0"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"

[tool.setuptools]
package-dir = {"" = "src"}
packages = [
    "package-a",
    "package-b",
]

[tool.setuptools.package-data]
"*" = [
    "path/to/*.txt"
]

[project]
name = "my-project"
version = "0.0.1"

authors = [
  { name="devnectar", email="a@b.com" },
]

description = "description goes here"
readme = "README.md"
requires-python = ">=3.10"

classifiers = [
    "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
    "License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License",
    "Operating System :: OS Independent",
]

dependencies = [
    "dep",
    "another-dep",
    "yet-another-dep"
]

[project.optional-dependencies]
dev = [
    "tox"
]

[project.urls]
"Homepage" = "https://some_url.com"
"Bug Tracker" = "https://some_url.com"

[project.scripts]
nectarserver = "entry-point-script"

[tool.tox]
legacy_tox_ini = """
    [tox]
    min_version = 4.0
    env_list = test_env

    [testenv]
    deps = pytest
    commands = pytest -s
"""
```

I also tried `test` and `tests` instead of `dev` when trying to get this to work.

I'm running into two issues:

- When I run `pip install -e .`, `tox` is not installed
- The `requires.txt` generated by the `install` command ends up having a `[dev]` section in it, which causes `pip install -r mypackage/mypackage.egg-info/requires.txt` to error out. This causes other issues down the road in my build chain, which relies on requirements.txt files generated during the build to generate a Docker layer with project dependencies in it.

How should I capture the dev only dependency on `tox` in my `pyproject.toml`?

Comment: related discussion: https://discuss.python.org/t/development-dependencies-in-pyproject-toml/26149

Answer (score 18):

[Extra dependencies](https://peps.python.org/pep-0508/#extras) work the same for local packages as they do for packages on PyPI; try

```bash
pip install -e .[dev]
```

Comment: By the way, you may need to quote that if your shell treats `[`/`]` as special characters: `pip install -e '.[dev]'`.